# YouTube API v3 with OAuth2: update and delete fail with "Insufficient Permission" error

Tags: ruby, api, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to `update` and `delete` videos using the [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) with [OAuth2 for authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) via the `google-api-client (0.6.4)` Ruby gem. However, when I attempt to execute either of these two actions, I see the following error message:

```
Google::APIClient::ClientError: Insufficient Permission
```

**Here's the odd thing:** Using the exact same authentication procedure as with `update` and `delete`, I can `insert` (upload) successfully, no problem! So, I do not believe this is a problem with my authentication setup, but somewhere else in my code.

My read-write `scope` is always the same across any of these actions:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
```

And according to the API documentation, that space-delimited set of scopes should cover `insert`, `update` and `delete` actions.

My `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token` are always the same for all these actions too -- so, that can't be the problem either, can it? Note that my program automatically obtains a new `access_token` when it expires, so, again, I do not believe that is where the problem lies.

To compare, here is what my `insert` (upload) code looks like (**this works**):

```
# Auth stuff, then...
@client.execute!(
  :api_method => @youtube.videos.insert,
  :body_object => body,
  :media => Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(file_path, 'video/*'),
  :parameters => {
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    :part => body.keys.join(','),
  }
)
```

And here is what my `delete` code looks like (**this fails**):

```
# Auth stuff, then...
@client.execute!(
  :api_method => @youtube.videos.delete,
  :parameters => {
    'id' => youtube_id,
  }
)
```

What am I missing? Unfortunately, the [YouTube API documentation for delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete) does not provide any examples, so I've got nothing to compare against. Please let me know if there is further information that I can provide to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm fairly sure all 11 views of this question (as of this writing) are me, but I'm going to post an answer just in case it helps someone in the future:

There was no problem with my code itself. The problem was when I initially created my `refresh_token` for this account.

For the uninitiated, the YouTube Data API (v3) does not support "service accounts," which, elsewhere in the Google API ecosystem, are the way you would normally accomplish setting up an OAuth2 auth'd client when the only client is yourself. The workaround is something you have to do *by hand*. Take the steps below:

---

First, go to the Google "API Console." There, under "API Access," you need to "Create a client ID" for an "installed application." This will give you a `Client ID`, a `Client secret` and a `Redirect URI` (you'll want the non-`localhost` one). Write these down.

Next, you need to **manually obtain an authorization code** by visiting a URL like the following in your favorite web browser, *while logged in to the same account you just created the client ID for*:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
  ?client_id={client_id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
  &scope={space separated scopes}
  &response_type=code
  &access_type=offline
```

Of course, you need to enter the `client_id`, `redirect_uri` and `scope` query parameters. In my case, **this is where I went wrong**. When I did this manual step, I should have put the `scope` param as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
```

But instead I just did `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`, which is insufficient to update/delete videos!

Last, you need to obtain a `refresh_token`, by taking a URL like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
  ?code={authorization_code}
  &client_id={client_id}
  &client_secret={client_secret}
  &redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
  &grant_type=authorization_code
```

And curl'ing it with a command like:

```
$ curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "code=..."
```

This will return a JSON response that contains your `refresh_token`, which you then use when authorizing your request programmatically through the Google API.

Comment: Here's another way to generate the refresh token to plug into your code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc

Comment: could you please similar problem [Uploading video to YouTube and adding it to playlist using YouTube Data API v3 in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174090/uploading-video-to-youtube-and-adding-it-to-playlist-using-youtube-data-api-v3-i)?

Comment: I was having the same error, but for update you need to add read write ssl scope. Referred from this link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update

Answer (score 0):

**NB** We are now in 2022, you need to include at least a youtube authorization scope if you are using Node.js or any other languages, I am just familiar with node.js only.

for example https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube for more check [youtube official](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/delete) documentation