# Uploading video to YouTube and adding it to playlist using YouTube Data API v3 in Python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api

I wrote a script to upload a video to YouTube using YouTube Data API v3 in the python with help of example given in [Example code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video).

And I wrote another script to add uploaded video to playlist using same YouTube Data API v3 you can be seen [here](https://github.com/alokmahor/add_to_youtube_playlist/blob/master/playlist.py)

After that I wrote a single script to upload video and add that video to playlist. In that I took care of authentication and scops still I am getting permission error. here is my new script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run

# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# A limited OAuth 2 access scope that allows for uploading files, but not other
# types of account access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# Helpful message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the APIs Console
https://code.google.com/apis/console#access

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

def get_authenticated_service():
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, storage)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def initialize_upload(title,description,keywords,privacyStatus,file):
  youtube = get_authenticated_service()

  tags = None
  if keywords:
    tags = keywords.split(",")

  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body=dict(
      snippet=dict(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        tags=tags,
        categoryId='26'
      ),
      status=dict(
        privacyStatus=privacyStatus
      )
    ),
    # chunksize=-1 means that the entire file will be uploaded in a single
    # HTTP request. (If the upload fails, it will still be retried where it
    # left off.) This is usually a best practice, but if you're using Python
    # older than 2.6 or if you're running on App Engine, you should set the
    # chunksize to something like 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  vid=resumable_upload(insert_request)

  #Here I added lines to add video to playlist
  #add_video_to_playlist(youtube,vid,"PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ")
  #youtube = get_authenticated_service()
  add_video_request=youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
                'snippet': {
                  'playlistId': "PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ", 
                  'resourceId': {
                          'kind': 'youtube#video',
                      'videoId': vid
                    }
                #'position': 0
                }
        }
    ).execute()


def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  vid=None
  while response is None:
    try:
      print "Uploading file..."
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if 'id' in response:
        print "'%s' (video id: %s) was successfully uploaded." % (
          title, response['id'])
    vid=response['id']
      else:
        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
    except HttpError, e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      print error
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print "Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)
  return vid  

if __name__ == '__main__':

  title="sample title"
  description="sample description"

  keywords="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3"

  privacyStatus="public"
  file="myfile.mp4"
  vid=initialize_upload(title,description,keywords,privacyStatus,file)
  print 'video ID is :',vid
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I am getting permission error. both script works fine independently.

could anyone help me figure out where I am wrong or how to achieve uploading video and adding that too playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer actually in both the independent script scope is different.
scope for uploading is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
scope for adding to playlist is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"

as scope is different so I had to handle authentication separately.

Comment: I can't do the 2 steps sequentially although i used the 2 scopes in the authentication!.

I must do them separately.
Did you get any solution to handle the 2 steps sequentially?

Comment: I did not try, I uploaded and added to playlist using two separate authentication

Comment: I just came upon your question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37343). Let me commend you on your inquiry, but I must say that you've asked at the wrong place. You correctly identified that almost every religion or faith system stipulates that some people are 'higher' than others, whether they are called 'more spiritual' or 'more knowledgeable about the truth'. But almost all belief systems are irrefutably incompatible with each other, so at most one can be correct, and possibly none. In my opinion, it's far better to think critically and listen to your own conscience.

Comment: Be aware that humans have a natural tendency to want to feel a sense of belonging to something, whether it is a group of people who like something or a group of people who profess some shared set of beliefs. You and I are no exception, and it is important to recognize this tendency to eliminate its biased influence on our assessment of beliefs. When people profess to have a guru/teacher/leader, they get a feeling that they are in a superior position to others who don't have one, even if they don't realize it.

Comment: @user21820: Thanks for writing. Please give me your email address or any other way to contact. mine is alokmahor@gmail.com