# Delete from my YouTube Channel Programmatically

Tags: php, youtube-api

Previously I had a working php script that uses the Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin Object to authenticate and make requests on my behalf to delete videos from my YouTube channel. Apparently, this has been deprecated because I get an error and read this: [zend gdata and google spreadsheet not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472059/zend-gdata-and-google-spreadsheet-not-connecting)

And I get an error which says no longer available. So I've been researching how to use YouTube API v3. Initially I created a service account via the Google developer console.

However I found this

[YouTube API v3 with OAuth2: update and delete fail with "Insufficient Permission" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126857/youtube-api-v3-with-oauth2-update-and-delete-fail-with-insufficient-permission)

Which states:

> For the uninitiated, the YouTube Data API (v3) does not support
>   "service accounts,"

And I need to manually obtain a refresh token, to make requests?

Is this still the case? Surely, there must be an easier way to make authenticated requests to the YouTube API where the only client is my server?

If this is still true, how long will the refresh token work? Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#Obtaining_Access_Tokens) to see the most up to date way to request the access token. When the access token expires, your application can refresh it by sending a POST request to Google's authorization server using the refresh token. You only need to get this refresh token **once** in order to refresh your access token, not every time you want to make authenticated requests, if that's what you were thinking.

The refresh token should be valid [unless](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration):

> - The user has revoked access.
> - The token has not been used for six months.
> - The user account has exceeded a certain number of token requests.

There is currently a 25-token limit per Google user account, so if your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into this limit and older refresh tokens will stop working.

I can't speak as to whether this is the best way of doing it, but I assume the developers chose this way for a reason.